# UIViewController Objective-C category not available in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I read in other questions that it is possible to use Objective-C category methods in Swift with no ease. Just import the `.h` file in the Bridging header.

I did it for my `UIViewController` category but I can't reach its methods from Swift (It's not an autocomplete problem... It can't compile).

Here is the code of the category... is there something strange or that I missed?

```
#import "UIViewController+LCSideMenuViewController.h"
#import "LCSideMenuViewController.h"

@implementation UIViewController (LCSideMenuViewController)

/**
 Return a reference to the root SideViewController (if exists)
 */

- (LCSideMenuViewController *)sideMenuViewController
{
    UIViewController *viewController = self.parentViewController;

    while (!(viewController == nil || [viewController isKindOfClass:[LCSideMenuViewController class]])) {
        viewController = viewController.parentViewController;
    }

    return (LCSideMenuViewController *) viewController;
}
```

Then I try to get the `sideViewController` in swift with this code:

```
import UIKit

class TutViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sideMenuViewController() ... 

    }
.
.
.
```

and my bridging header is just:

```
#import "UIViewController+LCSideMenuViewController.h"
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you also added the header in the compiler options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bridging header should also import the `LCSideMenuViewController`:

```
#import "LCSideMenuViewController.h"
```

The Swift code can't be compiled without also having the definition of the method's return type.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your category in the header file, it will be visible to the swift file. The fix is to move the category to `UIViewController+LCSideMenuViewController.h`.